# Did Batman use his cape to glide before The Dark Knight?

Tags: dc, batman

Has **comic-book** Batman ever used his cape for gliding or did he only use the [Batglider](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Batglider) for such a feat?

[image: Batglider]

I know that the fairly recent incarnations of Batman allows for his cape to possess rigid enough properties for gliding:

- Batman Beyond (Animated series)
- The Dark Knight Trilogy (Movie series)
- Arkham Asylum/City/Origins/Knight (Gaming series)

I'm guessing the gliding-with-my-cape thing is quite new as I don't remember seeing it happen in some of the older comics I've read, but maybe it did happen and I just missed it?

Comment: I’m pretty sure he also did it in the Burton Batmovies. Possibly Batman Returns.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Then I will have to watch those movies again :)

Comment: He definitely uses his cape to reduce the speed of his descent in *Batman* [1989], and I think he does it again in *Batman Returns* [1992].  But that's more like a parachute than a glider.

Comment: Batman indeed glides in *Batman Returns*. Before gliding he deploys from his cape two long and rigid bat wings. When he lands he retracts them back behind the cape.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In a word, yes.

**[Batman - The Brave and the Bold #64](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Brave_and_the_Bold_Vol_1_64) (1966)**

[image]

Comment: Cool, thanks for this!

Answer (score 16):

#### [Bob Kane and his co-creator Bill Finger](http://www.quora.com/Batman-creative-franchise/Would-it-be-fair-to-say-the-character-of-The-Shadow-had-a-powerful-influence-on-Bill-Fingers-and-Bob-Kanes-interpretation-and-creation-of-Batman/answer/Thaddeus-Howze) posited the idea of a Bat-type glider/cape as far back as 1939.

- These early images of Batman drawn in 1939 show the gliding "creature of the night" theme is as old as the character itself.

[image]

Comment: I can't make out the writing very clearly. Do you have a cleaner version of this pic?

Comment: @Richard [Here](http://i2.wp.com/codigoespagueti.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/17/2014/03/batman-bob-kane.jpg?resize=640%2C587).

Comment: @MrLister - Brilliant, cheers.

Comment: Brilliant stuff, very interesting!

Comment: Correction, our current view of batman was created by Bill Finger... not Bob Kane, who was given a deal by DC to sell out his co-creator for sole rights.

Comment: Yes, as I am well aware of after a great deal of research on the subject. Thank you for your notation.