# Batman cape as a glider and a bulletproof shield

Tags: dc, batman, technology, armor

In the most recent incarnation of Batman, namely in the film "The Flash" (2023) where he was portrayed by Michael Keaton, Batman has the most sophisticated and useful cape. The cape can turn into a glider, both for long flights (where he dropped himself from the Batwing and then glided to the ground) and for short flights (the pit scene). Moreover, the cape was bulletproof and Batman used it twice to shield the Flash from the bad guys' fire. The cape stopped bullets shot from an assault rifle, which is very impressive (but unrealistic).

Does such a cape exist also in the comics or in other adaptations?

Personally, I find this cape the coolest and I hope it will become part of the canon of Batman and a standard gear for the caped crusader.

Comment: I have encountered such capes in video games. Actually, glider cape is most common.

Comment: The question of Batman gliding has already been dealt with; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87166/did-batman-use-his-cape-to-glide-before-the-dark-knight/87170#87170

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/comicbooks/comments/8ttu0j/are_batmans_suit_and_cape_bulletproof/ might be useful for the bulletproof part.

Comment: There are definitely examples of Batman using his cape as a bulletproof shield in the comics, as well as examples of him using it as a glider. The question seems to be asking whether there are one or more specific versions of the cape in the comics that can do _both_ of those things, though. So establishing that it can do either one of those things separately doesn't answer this question, unless you can prove that the same cape (or the exact same type of cape) was worn in each instance.

Comment: [Behold my wings of steel!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batfink)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Batfink's wings were able to be magnetised. They weren't just *like* a shield of steel..